# strange warning messages preventing designer from opening file visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, warnings, designer

I have a form which is derived from an existing form. The existing form works perfectly. When I attempt to open the new form (for the first time) I get an error from the designer:

To prevent possible data loss before loading the designer, the following errors must be resolved:

Access to the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\Logs\eventlog.dat' is denied.

This file does not even exist. If I look at the call stack it gets even more strange. In the constructor of the form being derived from, there is a class that creates a log file.

```
at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize)
at MeterView.MVLogger..ctor() in C:\Users\glevenson\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MeterView\MeterView\MVDataLogger.cs:line 67
at MeterView.MVLogger.get_Instance() in C:\Users\glevenson\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MeterView\MeterView\MVDataLogger.cs:line 79
at MeterView.frmSingle..ctor() in C:\Users\glevenson\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MeterView\MeterView\frmSingle.cs:line 167
```

Which is referencing a line code that does in fact create a directory and log file, but from the applications current directory. This makes no sense at all.

Why is a warning being generated about a file that doesn't exist, and why is it preventing me from doing anything in the designer? At the moment I am completely dead in the water because of this.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Show the code for the MVLogger constructor, i.e., how it decides where to put the log file. You are probably making an incorrect assumption about the location of the log file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two mistakes you are making here.  The first one is that you don't specify the full path name of the file.  You are creating/opening the logging file by just specifying "eventlog.dat".  That goes wrong when the default working directory is not set where you hope it is.  It certainly isn't set anywhere happy in design mode.  It is *never* set correctly after you ship your project, you cannot write to a subdirectory of c:\program files.  You must use Environment.GetFolderPath() to select an AppData path that you can write to.

Second mistake is that you allow this code to run in design mode.  Use the DesignMode property to prevent that from happening.

Comment: I use Application.StartupPath as the parent directory of the Logs directory. Wrapping the instantiation of the logger object in DesignMode makes no difference. I still get the warning, the file does not get created where the warning is stating, and I still cannot open the form in the designer.

Comment: Well, clearly Application.StartupPath isn't going to work when the application didn't get started yet.  Focus on getting DesignMode working, you cannot get the form opened in design mode when your code throws an exception.  I cannot otherwise see your code from here.

Comment: thank you all for your replies. I never before realized that the designer is making decisions about my run time execution. DesignMode is my friend.

Answer (score 0):

Wild guess based on what you have there, but knowing Visual Studio, here are my guesses (that don't format well in a comment, so SO Gods, please forgive me):

1. `MVDataLogger` class has an issue due to lack of proper initialization
2. `MVDataLogger` attempts to load/read/write to a file called "Logs\eventlog.dat"
3. `MVDataLogger` is not ensuring that file/directory exists before opening it.

I believe fixing these items will resolve your issue.

Comment: MVDataLogger is a singleton class with a static instance. It does create a logfile called Logs\eventlog.dat, and works perfectly.

Comment: I have a feeling it doesn't work perfectly in the Designer environment.

Answer (score 0):

Error is generated by the code inside your constructor. Try to comment all the custom code of your constructor. If everithing is ok, uncomment lines until you got the error again. 
Try to avoid unsafe initialization in the constructor. Or use:

```
if(!DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this))
{
   // do something not dupported in designer 
}
```